# jQuery Accordion/Toggle Panel - Only close/open specific classes

Tags: javascript, css, accordion, jquery

Community!

I really need your help now. I wanted to make an accordion in which I can open all Tabs. By searching the Web I found a good solution:

http://jsbin.com/eqape/968/edit

The first Div-Container of each Section is the one who closes/opens up. I want to define 3 div-Containers. One at the top (always displayed), one in the center (with the toggle-functionality) and one on the bottom (always displayed). Is this possible ? And how can I do this ? I'm new to jQuery so this drives me crazy.

Thank you, guys!

Comment: Just for clarification: In your example you have 4 sections. On click on each you want to open its content. The content of each sections consists of 3 divs while the first is the sections div itself for click -> expand. The second one opens when clicked on the first and else it's hidden. The 3rd is always open? Like the Sections3 example in your code? So basicly everything you want to accomplish is how section 3 works at the moment?

Comment: I've got 4 Sections - right.
Each Sections has got 3 Divs. The First and the third div should always be visible. On Click I want only the Second div (which is between the first (top) and the third (bottom)) to open up/close itsself.

Comment: Isn't there a way to iterate through all following Divs (3) and ask them if any of them has got a specific classname (center) and only do the slideToggle()-Function to that one and only div ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying too hard. If I understand correctly, you simply want any .top to toggle the adjacent .content. Since I'm more familiar working in JSFiddle, I've set the code up there:

http://jsfiddle.net/SuyS2/1/

```
$('.top').click(function () {
  $(this).next('.content').slideToggle();
});
```

Let me know if I'm missing something.

UPDATE:

If you had wanted the sections *and* the inner content to toggle, you could do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/SuyS2/5/

```
$('.section-heading').click(function () {
  $(this).next('.section-wrapper').slideToggle();
});

$('.top').click(function () {
  $(this).next('.content').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: thank you so much. That was not 100% what I wanted. But with a few corrections I got it running how I wanted it:

http://jsfiddle.net/SuyS2/10/

Comment: You're welcome. Rather than doing stacked nexts, you could do: $(this).siblings('.content').slideToggle();